# Improving my MySQL revision system

Tags: mysql, revision

I have a revision system running in one of my projects.
A database table looks like the following:

```
objectID // (no primary/auto_increment!)
versionID
time
deletionTime
// (additionalFields)
```

The newest revision always has `versionID = 0`.
On an update, the entry with `versionID` = 0 gets updated to `MAX(versionID)+1`.
The updated entry will then be inserted with versionID = 0.
Also, the time of the insert will be saved.

The revision system works good like it is, but I have some difficulties with the system as it is at the moment:

I have another table with no revision system that is related to the revision table:

```
ID
parentID // the reference to the revision table
time
```

If I query entries out of this table, I need to join my revision table and get the revision that was relevant when my entry was created.
This means that I need a subquery to select all revisions with `revisionTable.time <= otherTable.time`
and then group by the entryID.

This does not seem to be a really good solution to me. There will be always a subquery needed for this.

I used this revision system with the current revision as "versionID = 0" because of the ability to easily query all current revisions over all objects.

My solution for a better revision system is as follows:

```
ID // primary, auto_increment
objectID // multiple revisions share the same objectID
isRevision // bool, the current revision has it set to 0
time
// (additionalColumns)
```

With this system, I could still query all current revisions and could use the primary ID of the revisions in my other table.

What do you think? Better ideas?